# How to display loading message until fetch is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

I have a list of items that are loaded from an API. If there are no items I should see a message stating that there are no items currently available. Now the thing is, this message is showing for a second or two, while the items are loading.
So my question is: How do I show e.g. "Loading items..." instead of the other message until all my items are rendered?

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Item from '../components/Item'

function Deals() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://gp-super-store-api.herokuapp.com/item/list")
    const data = await response.json()
    setItems(data.items)
    setIsLoading(false)
  }, [])

  const filter = items.filter((item) => item.isOnSale === true)

  if(filter.length === 0){
    return <h1>Sorry folks, nothing for sale today :(</h1>
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {items.filter((item) => item.isOnSale === true).map((item) => (
        <Item 
        name={item.name} 
        img={item.imageUrl} 
        price={"$" + item.price}
        onsale={item.isOnSale}
        starsNum={item.avgRating}
        stock={item.stockCount}
        id={item._id}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Deals;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally render using the loading state you have set.

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Item from '../components/Item'

function Deals() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://gp-super-store-api.herokuapp.com/item/list")
    const data = await response.json()
    setItems(data.items)
    setIsLoading(false)
  }, [])

  const filter = items.filter((item) => item.isOnSale === true)

  if(filter.length === 0){
    return <h1>Sorry folks, nothing for sale today :</h1>
  }
    return (
        <>
           { loading? "Loading items...":(
           <div>
              {items.filter((item) => item.isOnSale === true).map((item) => (
                <Item 
                name={item.name} 
                img={item.imageUrl} 
                price={"$" + item.price}
                onsale={item.isOnSale}
                starsNum={item.avgRating}
                stock={item.stockCount}
                id={item._id}
                />
              ))}
            </div> )}
         
            </>
          );
}
export default Deals;
```